# Issues starting Oxen Node after installing debs package on a fresh server

Tags: full-node, monero-forks, nodes, oxen, oxen-service-node

I'm trying to setup a Monero forked project: Oxen and doing a fresh install of its node on a new ubuntu 20.4 machine.

I'm following these instructions https://docs.loki.network/ServiceNodes/DebianPackageGuide/

```
sudo curl -s https://deb.loki.network/public.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb https://deb.loki.network $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/loki.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt install loki-service-node
```

After install and I tried to start it, I get the following errors in the log file /var/log/oxen/oxen.log:

[image]

This is a fresh install, what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure /var/lib/oxen/lmdb files are owned by _loki user otherwise you would get this error. This happens when users download the Oxen blockchain manually and then start oxen. Just change ownership of all files to _loki in that directory.